# what does css display:contents do?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I had a bug-like issue with a div inside a 'a' tag.

```
<a href=''>
  <div>..</div>
</a>
```

this `<a>` tag was inside a flex parent.
for some reason this `<a>` added a padding to the div(from right only). Padding wasn't shown in google chrome developer tools. But after trying many things I accidently tried the autosuggestion display: contents.
This removed that padding.

What is this display: contents do?
What does it do to `<a>` tag?

Comment: According to [the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box) : elements with `display: contents` don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.
Please provide a working exemple, it will help to better understand your issue.

Comment: thanks. Issue is solved with display:contents; just needed to know how.

Comment: display: contents causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself. This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

Comment: You should post more details. Just because `display: contents` fixed the problem, doesn't mean it actually addressed the problem.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> `display: contents` causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself. This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.

Source: https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents

Answer (score 0):

### What display:contents do and how it works? Explanation.

`display: contents` is an awesome feature for creating layouts.

It allows you to treat children of flex item or children of grid item just like they are flex/grid items themselves. In other words you can **"flatten out" nested DOM tree** to use it within one flex or grid system.

It is very convenient if you are not able - or for any reason don't want to - change the DOM structure of the current layout, but still **want to use flex/grid abilities** to move and reposition elements around - not only for siblings within flex/grid layout but also **for their children and grandchildren**.

### Simple flexbox example:

```html
<section style="display: flex">
   <div id="item-1">A</div>
   <div id="item-with-children" style="display: flex;">
         <span class="b1">B1</span>
         <span class="b2">B2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="item-3">C</div>
</section>
```

Flex container has three `<div>` flex items that will behave as with defined flexbox flow. For example you can use CSS property `order: 3` to change their order.

```css
#item-with-children { order: 3; }
```

Adding that will display this layout as:

> A C B1 B2

That way the second item (`div#item-with-children`) will be placed as third item in flex container.

Also there is another flexbox layout defined within `div#item-with-children` item and `<span>` items will flow independently from the main layout. `<span>` items will always be **inside** theirs parent `<div>`. Trying to add `order: 1` to any of the children will not reposition them in front of #item-1.

```css
span.b2 { order: 1; }
```

It will change only order between B1-B2 children and the result will be:

> A C B2 B1

### Using display: contents to reposition flex/grid item children

Adding `display: contents` to any flex-item that **is a parent** will **virtually change the structure** of the code so that it's children are on virtual-DOM **level same as the parent** itself.

The **structure will behave as flattened to only one level deep**.
While real DOM structure in facts doesn't change, you can imagine it works like this

```css
#item-with-children { display: contents; }
```

```html
<section style="display: flex">
    <div id="flex-item-1">A</div>
    <span class="b1">B1</span>
    <span class="b2">B2</span>
    <div id="flex-item-3">C</div>
</section>
```

So as you see `<span>` elements behave like they are siblings of `<div>` flex items, and now you are able to add `order: 1` to any of `<span>` which **will in fact** reposition it within all other flex-items.

```css
#item-with-children { display: contents; }
span.b2 { order: 1; }
```

Using `display: contents` **on parent** and `order: 1` **on child** element will result in:

> B2 A B1 C

Just like there were no child but only same-level siblings.

### Notes

- it is also possible to add `display: contents` to children elements - in that way grandchildren of the flex/grid item will behave like it's siblings
- `display: contents` can be use both for **flexbox** and **grid** layout systems
- in grid layout system you can also use `subgrid` which works in very similar way:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Subgrid
- (as of 2024) don't use display: contents on `<button>`, and table elements